# img tag wrapped in anchor tag not clickable

Tags: html, css

Take a look at my site -> [mangtolo](http://mangtolo.com/). When you click at the big comment button's image (exactly on the image), it doesn't take you anywhere. But when you click the surrounding `a` tag background, the link works.

How do I make it clickable(img tag) so that it takes me to the comment page? Is it supposed to be clickable but the structure of my html or CSS doesn't permit it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<div id="fblikebutton">` is positioned relative and is rendered on top of your comment button. Add a `background-color` and you'll see that it's blocking the comment button.

Comment: ooppss... never mind , just realized I had inline styling. It overrides it.

Answer (score 1):

if you'll change the CSS for #fblikebutton from

```
/* line 344 in home.css (according to Firebug) */
padding-left: 100px;
```

to:

```
margin-left: 100px;
```

it will fix your problem (which was that the Facebook like button was on top of that comment)

Comment: thanks.. but I found simpler solution, turns out I had inline styling lol but +1 anyways